# How to enable redis service in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, services, redis

I am trying to write an ansible role for redis stand-alone server installation. I downloaded the tarball from redis repo, extracted it and ran make commands to install it.

Then I made changes in configuration file, created directories and service file as mentioned [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04)

In the end when I try to enable the service in Ubuntu 14.04, it gives an error:

> Synchronizing state for redis with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
>
> Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d redis enable
>
> update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/redis: file does not exist

Works fine in ubuntu 16.04 but not in 14.04

I know that, Command `systemctl enable servicename` creates a soft link of service file in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants in ubuntu 16.04.
How does it happen in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 uses upstart instead of systemd. Also, 14.04 is EOL in one month.

Comment: I would recommend the apt - method: 'apt-get install redis-server' , then 'Service redis-server start' .. This should do the Job.

Comment: Thank you for you inputs. I needed a working **init** file in `/etc/init.d/` directory. This is how I did it:
1. installed server through install_server.sh script in utils directory in source code
2. got sample init file from it.
3. then used `update-rc.d <service> enable` command to enable service.